# HttpRequestValidationException workaround

Tags: c#, javascript, exception, httprequest

I have a textbox that when user inputs a string such as "<daily" (to signify less than daily) it throws a HttpRequestValidationException. However if there is a space between the less than symbol and the string, it works fine such as "< daily".

I have had it change the value that is submitted in the code behind by using the replace function. For example:

```cs
string s = "This is a <test";
if(s.Contains("<")){
   s = s.Replace("<", "< "); //I have also used "&#60;" & "&lt;"
}
```

However, I still get the exception because in the textbox it is still showing it as "<daily". I am wondering if there is a way that if the focus is off the textbox to dynamically add a space to the string?

I understand that the HttpRequestValidationException is not supposed to allow those characters, but it seems to allow if there are spaces. Any thoughts?

Comment: Without going into the whole debugger story, checking for `s.Contains` and then doing `s.Replace` is wasteful. `Contains` will iterate over all the characters in the worst cases and `Replace` will do that again. Just use `Replace` directly to iterate over the characters once. It doesn't throw an exception if nothing is found.

Comment: +1, Thanks for letting me know that. I will keep that in mind in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to know how you use the string in the HttpRequest. Depending on how and where you use we could come up with some ideas.

Comment: The string is not being used in the HttpRequest. When the focus comes off the form and I hit another link on the form, I get the HttpRequestValidationException. Our forms autosave when text is added initially or when you leave the form so you can return and edit them.

My thinking is that when focus is taken off the textbox a function adds a space between the symbol and the string. I was wondering if that is possible?